# Script works in PyCharm but not in Windows Command Line

Tags: java, python, windows, pycharm

The line of code that breaks it:

```
frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(f'{frame_folder}/*.jpg')]
frame_one = frames[0]
frame_one.save("X:\\Temp Photo Holder SolidScape Right\\resized\\progressRight.gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames,
               save_all=True, optimize=True, duration=33, loop=0)
```

The exception that gets thrown:

```
File "genGif.py", line 10
frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(f'{frame_folder}/*.jpg')]
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The Java that I use to call the Python:

```
try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String new_dir = "C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\rightProgressGifGen\\";
        rt.exec("cmd.exe /c cd \"" + new_dir + "\" & start cmd.exe /k \"python genGif.py\"");
        updateProgressRightGif();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        updateGlobalTime();
        System.out.println(e);
        tweet("Exception running emailTest().  Our time is " + globalHours + ":" + globalMinutes + ":" + globalSeconds);
    }
```

Code works in PyCharm and Idle but not command line.  Just need to be able to launch the script from Java somehow.

Comment: Could be your system variables point to the older version of Python (f-strings are introduced in Python 3.6)

Comment: @Mikey,
Your question look like want to show command line cannot python 3 script but your Java can do it.

Your Java code tries to use the command line to open the python 3 script. And it works.  Do I understand correct?

Answer (score 1):

Using string concatenation instead of `os.path.join` is a bad habit in multi-OS environment. Try that:

```
frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(os.path.join(frame_folder, '*.jpg')]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\rightProgressGifGen\genGif.py", line 44, in <module>
    make_gif("X:\\Temp Photo Holder SolidScape Right\\resized")
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\rightProgressGifGen\genGif.py", line 11, in make_gif
    frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(os.path.join(frame_folder), '*.jpg')]
TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(os.path.join(frame_folder))]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2968, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'X:\\Temp Photo Holder SolidScape Right\\resized'

Comment: Getting a "PermissionError" Permission Denied

Comment: Also, this will only ever be in a single-OS environment.  It will never run on anything but Windows.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the typo. I thought it was multi-OS because I saw `/`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your running Python3

I noticed in your exec function that you've written 'python genGif.py'

On some systems I've had to specify the version e.g. 'python3 genGif.py'

It would make sense that you would get an error with the f string as they weren't implemented until python3

Answer (score -1):

Should there be an "f" right after the opening parentheses in `glob.glob()`?

Comment: see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that was a thing. Learned something new.